# Custom CSS on a class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The footer of my (wordpress)website has the links for the privacy policy and T&Cs. On the rest of the site all links are blue. **I would like to override the natural blue color of the hyperlinks and make them white instead**:

```
/* Links--------------------------------------------- */
a {
color: #2557AA;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have a class in the footer called `colophon`. This is defined as a class to get special formatting. I want the link to appear white. I wrote the following to override the css for the hyperlink so that in the footer it would be white:

```
/* Footer--------------------------------------------- */
#colophon p {
line-height: 1.5;
color: #FFF;
}
#colophon a {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Footer.php

```
<footer id="colophon" >

    <p align="left"> All rights reserved.
    </p>

        <a href="http://example.com/TC">Terms of Use</a> | 
        <a href="http://example.com/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a> 


</footer><!-- end colophon -->
```

Comment: ... and you need help with what?

Comment: please re-create this scenario using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), then people can help you better... take my word on this ;)

Comment: Ha sorry about that...see the bolded section

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any problems with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with important

```
#colophon a {
   color: #FFF !important;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: remember that important overwrite whole style for this element

Comment: It is better to fix it properly than rely on !important alone.  !important just ups the priority of this css rule to the point it can't be modified by anyone or anything for any reason.  Obviously this makes it hard for it to be changed later and is considered a bad practice for any code that will ever be reused or have to be modified by anyone else.  You just have another rule somewhere over-riding the #FFF color for a.  Which means more code loaded.  More rules overwritten, best practice is to eliminate it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Links in the div #colophon will be white with the following code.

```
#colophon a:link {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}
#colophon a:visited {color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;}
#colophon a:hover {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}
#colophon a:active {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}
```

This way lets you changed the color depending on the mouse and if is previously viewed.  Having it change on hover helps the user know it is a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use [!important](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/)

```
#colophon a {
color: #FFF !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```